# text in three.js: transparency lost when rotating

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying the second approach to [use Text in three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Text-in-Three.js), drawing on a canvas and using the result as a texture. It basically works, except for the following problem -don't know if it's a bug:

I create two texts, with transparent background, and overlap then. They show ok, but when I rotate one of them, the transparency is messed up.

I create the text objects with following (excerpt) function

```
function createText(text, ...){
    var textHolder = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    var ctext = textHolder.getContext('2d');
    ...
    var tex = new THREE.Texture(textHolder);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: tex, overdraw: true});
    mat.transparent = true;
    mat.map.needsUpdate = true;
    var textBoard = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(textHolder.width, textHolder.height),mat);
    textBoard.dynamic = true;
    textBoard.doubleSided = true;
    return textBoard;
}
```

and add them to the scene. 
See demonstration with full code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonbloy/SXA8n/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparency is tricky in webGL.

The best solution in your case is to do the following for your transparent text material:

```
mat.depthTest = false;
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SXA8n/4/

three.js r.55

Comment: Sadly, this fixes the transparency problem in the interaction of the two texts, but on the other hand it breaks the interaction with other objects. See my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/leonbloy/2XTnr/  (the only difference with yours is that the sphere is placed near, so it -should- obstruct the texts) See the effect when one uncomments the line `mat.depthTest = false;` Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leonbloy/dfcJe/1/
Perhaps I'd switch to CanvasRenderer ?

Comment: Yes, there are tradeoffs. That is just a side effect of requiring transparency.